# Safest way to set up MySQL public server iMac

Tags: php, mysql

I am taking a few sql and database courses online and have been using the provided servers to run code. I wanted to build my own database so I set up a MySQL account on my iMac with snow leopard. Without reading too deeply into safety precautions, I can tell I learned a great deal from my mistake. This bad idea resulted in my password being cracked and the biggest headache ensued trying to figure out what happened. I had to wipe the entire computer. I couldn't believe how malicious the packet injected into my very novice server attempt was...

Does anyone have any techniques how to ensure safety so this doesn't happen again? I don't want to pay a site and am trying to build this on my own. Can I set up precautions like never allowing access to my mic/webcam? Can I identify when someone is attempting to crack my password? Any terminal code with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I had to wipe the entire computer" What could you have possibly done for that to happen? Joking aside, if I understand, you're trying to understand MySQL on your Mac? What security problems did you hit? Try to give more specific details into your problem and everyone here can help you better.

Comment: Don't do this. There are hundreds of free hosting providers that you can use to host your database and website while you are learning allthis. Obviously, you can set up a development environment on your mac, just do not make it available on the Internet. IT security experts are paid stellar amounts to secure online systems and even they get it wrong on more than one occasion. How do you think you will fare?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to secure MySQL is **never expose port 3306 to the public internet**.

If you need to connect to your machine remotely you should connect via a VPN, or SSH tunnel.

Most home routers have some basic port-forwarding and routing port 22 to your iMac should be fine. Just be sure **password authentication is off** and you're using SSH keys only.